# siunitx best way to represent quantities in power of 10s and with a multiplier

Tags: siunitx

I'm using package `siunitx` for the international system units.
I sometimes wish to represent quantities such as `1.977x10^20 N` and I always result to the optional argument of `parse-numbers=false`. I know I can use it as a global setting but I think like there should be a better and more standard way then what I'm doing sparkling `parse-numbers=false` all over the place.
Here's an example:

```latex
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{1.977 \cdot 10^{20}}{\newton}
```

Comment: The correct input is `\SI{1.977 e20}{\newton}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the correct input syntax for exponents `\SI{1.977e20}{\newton}` in combination with an appropriate `exponent-product` option as shown in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot}

\begin{document}
\SI{1.977e20}{\newton}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I knew there was a better way :)
Also can you show the use of `exponent-product`?